# How to remove part of a model?

Tags: modeling

I want to remove the roof section of this batmobile model, I'd like to know if there is a faster way of doing this than selecting all the individual vertices and moving them away, as this looks quite tricky. What is the best approach?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Separate by selection*.

1. Select the *faces* you want to remove
2. Use *Mesh > Separate > By Selection*
3. Your selection is now a separate object you can hide/show at will

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Select Face
- Ctrl + Select Face on the other side
  Blender will search the shortest path along the faces and will select all of them

or

- Press B to box select

or

If you've already assigned different materials (i.e. the glass window) you can select every face assigned to that material in the materials tab, or by pressing Ctrl + L and clicking on "Material" in the bottom left corner of your screen.